# Global variable useage in Windows( ).Activate

Tags: excel, global-variables, vba

I have set some Global variables and they are working, without the GV I have `Windows("LimeSurveyTokenTable.csv").Activate` and this is working.

I need `Windows("LimeSurveyTokenTable_ & strA & .csv").Activate` where strA is a Global variable

This is not working

There is a file called `LimeSurveyTokenTable_ Andrea.csv` where `strA=Andrea`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the variables value in between the two literal strings, which requires additional closing and opening double-quotes:

> Windows("LimeSurveyTokenTable_" & strA & ".csv").Activate

Comment: Hello David, it turns out that `Windows("LimeSurveyTokenTable_" & strA & ".csv").Activate` has to be `Windows("LimeSurveyTokenTable" & "_" & strA & ".csv").Activate`. It did not like the `LimeSurveyTokenTable_`.